# Regular expression for selecting part of string and excluding another part of string

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, replace

I have one string as variable and I want to use str.replace to replace each search string hit with `<span style="..."> + search string + </span>`. The problem is that I do this in loop in which the search string changes and some times the search string is similar to span or style. When this happens the result could be something like this `<span <span style="...">style</span>="...">search string</span>` which is catastrophic. So I need someone to help my by creating regular expression which selects the search string and excludes `<span style="...">` and `<span>` or give me an idea how to solve this.

Here is parth from my code which needs to be changed:

```
if ($("#search_criteria  option:selected").text() == lng("note_text_txt", "note_text_txt") &&   $("#search_note").val().trim() != "")
{
    var SearchArr = $("#search_note").val().split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < SearchArr.length;i++)
    {
        data["text"] = data["text"].replace(RegExp(SearchArr[i], 'g'), "<span style='color:red;'>" + SearchArr[i] + "</span>");
    }
}
```

`var SearchArr` has words which need to be found in `data["text"]` and replaced.

Comment: "which is catastrophic" it will be, if you parse HTML.. with regex

Comment: @AmitJoki I agree that parsing HTML with regex could bring many headaches but if they are used correctly they can be very useful. You can take a look at my answer for check a regex approach to parse the html needed in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer to provide you a regex to match and get content between your `<span>...</span>`.

But, I'm not sure what exactly you want to do. You can post some comments to help me understand your fully needs so I can update the answer to give an accurate post.

For the moment, I leave you the regex and a demo below.

### **Matching and get content regex**

```
<span.*?>(.*?)<\/span>
```

Here you can see a **[working example](http://regex101.com/r/oX3wD7/2)**

[image]

On the other hand, you can use another option for replace the content.

### **Replace content regex**

```
(<span.*?>)(.*?)(<\/span>)
```

Here you have the **[working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oX3wD7/3)**

[image]

Hope to help.

Comment: You answer is good for a beginning it excludes the span tag which is what I wanted but it selects all the text. I need only certain word or part of word, for example in your example I want to select only blo. How I need to modify your regex?

Comment: @DLP You can access in both regex to the text you want using the content of capturing group. In the links provided you can check the Match Information to see the group content. By the way, in the second link I show you how to use the 2nd group to replace the content. To use the content of capturing group you have to you `\n` where `n` is the number for the group. It is `\1` in the first regex and `\2` in the second to get the content you want

Comment: @DLP btw, in the screenshots you can see that the content of groups appear in colours. Green for the first regex and pink in the second.

Comment: Now that I tested your regex I noticed that it replaces the contend in the spans which is not my goal. Here is another example of what I am trying to do. I have the string `test1 test2 tes<span style="color:red;">t3</span> span test4` and I want to put span tag surrounding the `span` word which position is after `</span>` without touching the existing span tag. I hope you understood me.

Comment: @DLP I think that is a different question than what you posted actually the opposite. I'll be glad to help you but you should create a new question and close this one. The answer I provided you is for the question you asked. But I think you need something completely different than your question. My suggestiong is to create a new question with the content of your previous comment, and let me know so I can help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042498/manipulating-string-with-html-tags-using-regex

Comment: @DLT I saw that someone already answered to your question with a nice answer with regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using JQuery, you could replace the actual tag contents using selectors of the library.

I would think like this:

```
$(data['text']).find('*:contains(SearchArr[i])').text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(SearchArr[i], '<span>');
});
```

Take this as an idea and example. In an actual use you should specify better the elements above selected by *. The 'all' selector combined with :contains would take a big hit on the performance.

**Edit:**

It will work with your plain text just as well. If you provide valid HTML for a constructor of JQuery object, the DOM element packed in JQuery object gets created and you can operate on it in any way you would on any one selected from the document. Have a look at the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vk7N3/1/

Comment: The problem is that the text is plain and I need to put the span tags not replace them with the matches.