# Manipulating string with html tags using regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

I have the string `test1 test2 tes<span style="color:red;">t3</span> span test4` and I want to put span tag surrounding the `span` word which position is after `</span>` without touching the existing span tag using javascript regex.

Comment: That sounds like manipulating HTML, which shouldn't really be done with regex, but with something that can actually parse HTML.

Comment: `str.replace('span', '<span>span</span>')`?

Comment: @pattmorter - and that would replace the first span only, giving `test1 test2 tes<<span>span</span> style ...`

Comment: @adeno you're right... idk what i was thinking haha.

Comment: str.replace(' span ', ' <span>span</span> ') ? With spaces surrounding span word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REgex:

```
(<\/span> )(span)
```

REplacement string:

```
$1<span>$2</span>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/23)

```
> 'test1 test2 tes<span style="color:red;">t3</span> span test4'.replace(/(<\/span> )(span)/g, "$1<span>$2</span>")
'test1 test2 tes<span style="color:red;">t3</span> <span>span</span> test4'
```

Comment: For the current example your answer is correct, but lets think more golabaly. I want to do the same think but with any word or part of word that is close to the text from the span tag. For example `pa` from `span`

Comment: That is close but the result I want is this: `'test1 test2 tes<span style="color:red;">t3</span> s<span>pa</span>n test4'` is it possible?